# Problem with VMware Workstation 8.06

Tags: kernel, vmware

I am a new Linux user, and I'm currently using the latest version of Lubuntu. I want to create a virtual machine with VMware because in VirtualBox I am not able to use DirectX in Windows XP. Even after installing it on the operating system, it says it has no DirectX installed.

Because I prefer to use VMware (since I downloaded VMware for Windows) I tried to use it in Ubuntu, but VMware won't work as it does in Windows, so I downloaded VMware version 8, but I am not able to use it because of the following error:

```
Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.
Kernel Header 3.16.0-25-generic
Kernel headers for version 3.16.0-25-generic were not found. 
If you installed them in a non-default path you can specify the path below.   
Otherwise refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions and click Refresh to search again in default locations.
```

Comment: Please Translate in ENGLISH ..

Comment: You need to install the development headers for your kernel.  That will permit this to work.  HOWEVER, Shared Folders will not work due to a bug in vmware tools as a result of newer kernels.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the headers for your version of the kernel.

In this case, you're on Utopic (based on your kernel version in the error), so you'll need the `linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic` package.  This will install the headers: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic`

Comment: Desculpe colocar mais de um comentário, porém não coube tudo em um comentário.

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic já é a versão mais nova.
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-pt

Comment: kde-l10n-ptbr lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libgconf2-4 libgsoap5 libvncserver0
  libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk-media2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 openjdk-7-jre-headless
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion tzdata-java
Utilize 'apt-get autoremove' para os remover.
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 10 não atualizados.

Comment: @CamiloGusmão please use ENGLISH - This is a primarily English site and I do not have the ability to read non-English.